# VB.NET Randome Function to replace values

Tags: vb.net, random, replace

I have a Random Function in vb.net like this which returns the 6-digit alphanumeric string like this.

```
Public Function rand() As String
        Dim rng As Random = New Random
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        ' Selection of pure numbers sequence or mixed one
        Dim pureNumbers = rng.Next(1, 11)
        If pureNumbers < 7 Then
            ' Generate a sequence of only digits
            Dim number As Integer = rng.Next(1, 1000000)
            Dim digits As String = number.ToString("000000")
            For i As Integer = 1 To 6
                Dim idx As Integer = rng.Next(0, digits.Length)
                sb.Append(digits.Substring(idx, 1))
            Next
        Else
            ' Generate a sequence of digits and letters 
            Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
            For i As Integer = 1 To 6
                Dim idx As Integer = rng.Next(0, 36)
                sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
            Next
        End If
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

The problem is that when it returns `0` or `O` or `1` or `I`  and so on `{"1", "I", "O", "0", "5", "S", "7"}`

I want to replce these character with 'A' and then should return the final random string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this (untested):

```
 dim exceptionLetters = _
     {"1", "I", "O", "0", "5", "S", "7"}

 Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
 For i As Integer = 1 To 6
     Dim idx As Integer = rng.Next(0, 36)
     Dim ltr = s.Substring(idx, 1)
     if (exceptionLetters.Contains(ltr))
         Return sb
     End If
     sb.Append(ltr);
 Next
```